# I would like to password protect my entire Wordpress site (ip validated), except for one page

Tags: password, validation

I am currently using the .htaccess file in cPanel to password protect my Wordpress website. There are a list of whitelisted IP addresses that can bypass the login form.

I would like to whitelist a page, but I don't have a .php or .html file to whitelist. It is a page within Wordpress, so I realize I may have to find a plugin or another way to do this. I don't want to have to manually password protect literally every single page just so I can have one page open to the public, so... there must be a way to do this.

If anyone can help out, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are just wanting a simple "login" you could use `htpasswd` and `htaccess`. WordPress sites already have the `htaccess` in the main directory.

Add an `.htpasswd` file at the same level as your root HTML folder. Example:

```
. 
├── public_html
|   └── wordpress
|      └── .htaccess
└── .htpasswd
```

Use a tool like [htpasswd generator](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/) to generate a username/password pair. Then add this to your `.htpasswd` file.

Find the path `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` may provide some insight for you.

Edit WP's `.htaccess`. After the `#END WORDPRESS#` add

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/mysite/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

If you need more detailed instructions see [this post](https://www.zigpress.com/2014/09/22/password-protecting-an-entire-wordpress-site/).

However, this does not address your request about IP Validation. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419592/htaccess-htpasswd-bypass-if-at-a-certain-ip-address) on StackOverflow may address it.

You would update the `.htaccess` file to read

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/mysite/.htpasswd
AuthName "Please Log In"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
satisfy any
```

Comment: Hi Greg, thank you a lot for answering. I don't see exactly where I would place the "exceptions" for the page(s) that I don't want to password protect, though. Since my site is created mostly with the wordpress dashboard as opposed to uploading individual .php and .html files, I can't write exceptions for individual .php and .html pages. I would need to find a way to write an exception for a page (e.g., http://mysite.wordpress.com/job-listings) within that code, and that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to dive further into this but will try later tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: @MarinaRose all of my testing with the `.htaccess` method seem to have failed. Apologies for not being able to assist further.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `page-whitelist_content_page_slug.php` on your *theme* folder and add required rules.

**OR**

In `page.php` try this condition:

```
<?php if (is_page(page_ID) ){ ?>
    //content for whitelist page 
<?php } 
else if(is_user_logged_in()){ ?>
 //Content for all pages
<?php } ?>
```

**OR**

These plugins May help you:

1) **[WP Private Content Plus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-private-content-plus/)**

Main features:

- Restrict entire posts/pages/custom post types
- Restrict content by User Groups
- Restrict content by User roles
- Restrict content for Guests or Members
- Restrict content by User role Levels
- Restrict content by WordPress capabilities
- Private Page for user profiles
- Restrict menu for members, guests, user roles, user groups
- Restrict widgets for members, guests, user roles
- Restrict post attachments and downloads to for members, guests
- Restrict content by multiple user meta keys
- Restrict content by multiple user meta values
- Restrict search content by user types
- Integration with User Profiles Made Easy
- Global Site Protection with Single Password

2) **[Redirect to login if not logged in](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirect-to-login-if-not-logged-in/)**

Redirect user to login page if not logged in

NB: *Both plugins are free*